# Processing a apply statement to get column names for each row faster in python

Tags: python, pandas, performance, lambda, apply

I am trying to get the column names which match a particular string `"Buy"` for each row of a data frame(df). So if there are 2 columns matching `"Buy"` then both the column names are considered.
I have tried out the below code which works perfectly but it takes a long time for execution. Is there a way to improve its performance, as I can see the apply statement is impacting the performance. I have heard about vectorization/swifter apply to improve performance , but I am not able to understand how to apply it for my specific requirement.

#### Step1:

Get column names having `'_buy_sell'` as a partial string in its column name:

```
[Col_Buy_Sell]==[col for col in df.columns if '_buy_sell' in col]
```

#### Step2:

In the selected columns in step 1 ,if  any of the value is `'Buy'` then all those column names are moved to field `'Final_Buy'`. The multiple columns are separated by ",":

```
df['Final_Buy']=(df[Col_Buy_Sell] == 'Buy').apply(lambda y: (','.join(df[Col_Buy_Sell].columns[y])), axis=1)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add an example of the data and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to populate a new column with the names of all the columns in each row that have the value 'Buy' try this.

```py
df['Final_Buy'] = df.eq('Buy').dot(df.columns + ',').str.rstrip(', ')
```